# TabNavigator reset

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I have a problem with TabNavigator and StackNavigator in react-native. I would like to reset my navigation when I press a button.
I have my Stack Navigation in my Tab Navigation. The problem is that I can reset just one navigation ...

plan:

```
-tabNavigator
   -listing.js
   -stackNavigator
      -types.js
      -picture.js
      -ad.js
```

so when I am in ad.js I have a button when i click on it, my stackNavigation reset to type.js and tabNavigator on Listing.js
So i whould like to return Linsting.js in finally.

my navigation : navigation.js

```
export const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Types'}),
  ],
  key: null
})
export const listingAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'Listing',
  })


const Stack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Types: {screen: SelectTypesScreen},
    Picture: {screen: SelectPictureScreen},
    Ad: {screen: CreateAd}
  })

const Tab = TabNavigator(
  {
    Listing: {screen: ListingScreen},
    Preference: {screen: PreferencesScreen},
    Add: {screen : Stack}
  },
  {

  }
)

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <Tab />
      );
    }
  }
```

tab Navigation linsting.js

```
export default class Listing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Listing </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

stack navigations ad.js

```
export default class CreateAd extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={{marginTop: '80%', marginLeft: '40%'}}> Ad </Text>
                <Button title="Ok" onPress={() => {console.log("displayer 1"), this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction), console.log("displayer 2"), this.props.navigation.dispatch(listingAction)}} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to change your Navigations nested structure. Better go with exact way as docs. A root navigator can be a stacknavigator and you can add tabnavigator to it as a screen

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Recent: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
  All: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
});

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
  Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
});
```

Refer docs
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting